# Problem with rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI I don't know what happened  I ran rviz very well but after 2 hours  I can't run rviz

when I type  "rosrun rviz rviz" , I got this error :

> /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rviz/rviz: symbol
> lookup error:
> /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librviz.so:
> undefined symbol:
> _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126026/problem-with-rviz/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have you tried to update your system recently?  Try this again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-02-04**:
This should work. There was a problem with `rosconsole` and ABI compliance at one point.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-02-04**:
I use "sudo apt-get -f install" then my rviz run properly.But I don't know what's happen after this command.